# Writing Regular Expressions for a C string

Tags: c, regex, string

I am currently learning about regex and I am trying to figure out how to capture a string in C that does not allow newlines. I have searched around and found answers regarding flex and lex but I'm trying to learn it a simplistic as I can to gain a better understanding.

This is a piece of expression that I have found searching and it appears to be common(I have found it a lot). But I still have yet to find a clear explanation as to what it means and how it is used.

```
\"(\\.|[^"])*\"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What this expression means is that there must be a doublequote at the beginning and at the end `\"`, and there will be a sequence of zero or more o the following:

- A backslash character `\\` followed by any single character `.`, or
- A non-doublequote character `[^"]`

The first clause is self-explanatory. The second clause is there to treat any single character preceded by backslash as an *escape sequence*. This ensures that the expression would capture any of the following strings to the end:

```
"string \"one\" has embedded doublequotes"
"string two \
is split across \
multiple lines"
"string\tthree\nhas\tembedded\tescape\tcharacters"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The `\"` did not make since to me at all but your description made everything clear to me thank you! I'll accept the answer when it lets me.

Comment: Everything inside `[]` is usually escaped, so `[^\"]` would mean "everything but backslash or quotes". (It differs from OP here.)

Comment: @mafso You are right, the string is slightly inconsistent: the doublequotes at the beginning and at the end are escaped as if they were part of a string literal, while the doublequote inside the brackets is not escaped.

Comment: Would you by chance know of a simpler string? To me `\"(\\.)*\"` seems like it could work, am I wrong?

Comment: @MrCptObvious Your string matches a sequence of zero or more escape sequences enclosed in doublequotes, because `\\.` means "a sequence of precisely two characters such that the first character is a backslash, and the second character is any character at all".

Comment: So if I have this right the output could be, \a\a\ \a  ?

Comment: @MrCptObvious Yes, `\"(\\.)*\"` would let you match `"\a\a\ \a"`.

Comment: Awesome! I think I've got it! If i could upvote you more I would :)